# How to get the web socket (WS) tab data just indicating the website url?

Tags: python, java, selenium-webdriver, websocket, webdriver

I want to enter a website that has several sub urls of the type ([www.google.com/123](http://www.google.com/123) or [www.google.com/3212](http://www.google.com/3212)), whenever I enter each sub url the websocket request url is different, this is the first point , the second is I want to get the data I receive from this websocket,
the website in question receives 3 binary messages from websocket and I want to read these binary messages. As simple as that, is it possible to do this?

I tried with javascript but i need always a new request url.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with the following code snippet?

```
 // Replace 'wss://example.com/' with the actual WebSocket URL base
const baseUrl = 'wss://example.com/';

// Replace '123' and '3212' with your specific sub-URLs
const subUrls = ['123', '3212'];

// Function to create WebSocket connection for a given sub-URL
function connectWebSocket(subUrl) {
  const socketUrl = baseUrl + subUrl;
  const socket = new WebSocket(socketUrl);

  // Event listener for WebSocket connection open
  socket.addEventListener('open', (event) => {
    console.log(`Connected to WebSocket at ${socketUrl}`);
  });

  // Event listener for WebSocket binary messages
  socket.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    // Assuming the data is received as an ArrayBuffer
    const binaryData = event.data;
    console.log(`Received binary data for ${socketUrl}:`, binaryData);

    // Add your binary data processing logic here
  });

  // Event listener for WebSocket connection close
  socket.addEventListener('close', (event) => {
    console.log(`WebSocket connection closed for ${socketUrl}`);
  });

  // Event listener for WebSocket connection error
  socket.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
    console.error(`WebSocket error for ${socketUrl}:`, event);
  });
}

// Connect to each WebSocket with different sub-URLs
subUrls.forEach((subUrl) => {
  connectWebSocket(subUrl);
});
```

- Replace the baseUrl variable with the actual WebSocket URL base.
- Replace the subUrls array with the specific sub-URLs you want to connect to.
- The connectWebSocket function creates a WebSocket connection for a given sub-URL and sets up event listeners for open, message, close, and error events.

Comment: The problem is that when I enter the sub url the request url changes, I will always give an example of what changes:

wss://example.com/VWcuiI35N/cQ3JT_J7u?sessionId=-36GkuXfx

"sessionid" It changes every time I enter the website

" VWcuiI35N/cQ3JT_J7u " this is different in every sub url but it stays always the same in that sub url

How can i get this websocket url automatically? its possible?

Asking this because when i try to write manually the request url i always get rejected error